# Can someone explain how '&' works in this situation?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm finding it difficult to find an answer to this question.

Someone once showed me how to find common elements in an array:

```
> colours1 = %w(red green blue)
> colours2 = %w(orange red black blue)
> colours1 & colours2
=> ["red", "blue"]
```

But I don't understand what the '&' does in this code, how does it find the common elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer **what** it does, I cite [the documentation of `Array#&`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-26):

> Set Intersection — Returns a new array containing elements common to
>   the two arrays, excluding any duplicates. The order is preserved from
>   the original array.

As to **how** it does it, I point you to the [rubinius implementation of `Array#&`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/array.rb#L190)<sup>1</sup>:

```
def &(other)
  other = Rubinius::Type.coerce_to other, Array, :to_ary

  array = []
  im = Rubinius::IdentityMap.from other

  each { |x| array << x if im.delete x }

  array
end
```

Using `each { |x| array << x if im.delete x }` only elements being in `self` (the first array) get added to the returned array, if they are included in the `other` array.

---

<sup>1</sup> Please note that c-ruby implements things slightly different than rubinius or jruby do it. But it should give you an idea on what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is defined so. The [`Array#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-26) method takes another array and returns the intersection.